# Chrome is extremely persistent in caching Vue application

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm running into an issue with **Chrome** caching my **Vue 3** application.

The application was initially created about a year ago, and going through various updates, but I'm having a hard time making "it" (Chrome) understand to get a new version.

The application is deployed behind **Nginx** in the `/app` directory.

When I visit the `/app/` url, the app will load a login page, or if the user is logged-in: the user's last document (ie `/app/edit/12345`). If I *then* do a Shift reload, it correctly loads the up to date Vue app by force-reloading `/app/edit/12345`.

However if I then go back to `/app/`, it will reload (and reroute the user to `/app/edit/12345` using the *old* application.

For this, Nginx is configured using:

```
location ~* /app.*$ {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            #
            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            #
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }
        index  /app/index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html;
    }
```

This is what Inspector shows me for the `/app/` resource (which loads `/app/index.html`

[image]

Some of the more or less obvious things that do not have the right effect.

- Disable cache checkbox in Developer mode
- Clearing cookies and local storage for the domain
- Clearing cached images and files
- Enabling OPTIONS headers in Nginx
- Turn off Ad Block

Comment: PS So far all signs seem to point to the service-worker being the culprit.